# Cordova: Navigator.vibrate not working and returning undefined

Tags: android, cordova, vibration

I am building a cordova app and testing it on an Android device. I am attempting to use the cordova vibrate plugin but to make the app vibrate in response to certain user inputs, but I am not having success. I'm using cordova 9 and I've installed cordova-plugin-vibration. I'm creating my vibrate function on deviceready, to call from the app.

```
    let appFunctions = {};
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){        
            appFunctions.vibrate = function(arg) {
                navigator.vibrate(arg);
            }
    })
```

I've also enabled permissions to vibrate in the confix.xml file.

```
<config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> 
</config-file>
```

But when I call appFunctions.vibrate while testing on my android device, nothing happens, and when I ping the results of the navigator.vibrate function to my testing server, it returns undefined. Am I missing anything? Has anyone encountered this issue before?